# Command line batch image cropping tool

Tags: image, image-manipulation, crop, os-agnostic

is there any lightweight command line batch image cropping tool(Linux or Windows) which can handle a variety of the formats ?

Comment: Is there anything else about your system you'd like to tell us? for example, which OS?

Comment: Either Linux or Windows.I have both on my little netbook

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is what you want -- tried and true.

Comment: Thought I would share this, I tried pasting the link in MSN messenger to a friend and no matter what it seems it's on a blacklist of MSN.  I had to make tinyurl in order to share it.  Strange.

Comment: That is very weird. Does MSN Messenger still exist anyway? ;)

Comment: Haha, well, I use Pidgin and it still uses the protocol that MSN had, I believe.  Strange the domain would be blocked though.

Comment: This answer doesn't mention any concrete reason for why they would want it nor how to specifically use it for cropping.

Answer (score 61):

In Linux you can use

```
mogrify -crop {Width}x{Height}+{X}+{Y} +repage image.png
```

for CLI image manipulation

Comment: homebrew makes short work of this in Mac OS X also. `brew install imagemagick` Then to see your new goodies... `ls -lrt /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: Note that this doesn't _actually_ crop the image _data_, it only blanks the area sorrounding the cropping rectangle and writes the new dimensions+offsets into image metadata, but the 'physical' dimensions of the image will not be changed.

Because of this, this method doesn't work well with GIFs for example.

Comment: P.S. to _actually_ crop the image in the sense in which this operation is commonly understood, use the `+repage` argument along with the crop operator.

Comment: Additionally: trying this I got very confused, until I figured out that the image was actually rotated and the image viewer autorotated it upright. (The right orientation is contained in metadata/exif data I think.) To fix this, I used this: `mogrify -alpha on -auto-orient *.jpg`

Comment: @ReactiveRaven Link dead

Comment: NOTE that `mogrify` will overwrite the image, while `convert` will write to a new one

Answer (score 58):

Imagemagick's convert does the trick for me (and much more than cropping):

```
convert -crop +100+10 in.jpg out.jpg
```

crops 100 pixels off the left border, 10 pixels from the top.

```
convert -crop -100+0 in.jpg out.jpg
```

crops 100 pixels off the right, and so on. The Imagemagick website knows more:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop

Comment: Worth mentioning that ImageMagick's `convert` also offers autocrop/autocropping, throug the `-trim` option.

Comment: `-trim` is terrific!  It cuts out all the white margins automatically.

Answer (score 7):

I found [`nconvert`](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/) pretty handy so far.

Answer (score 6):

```
for f in final/**/*;
do
   convert -crop 950x654+0+660 "$f" "${f%.jpg}".jpg
done
```

This script loops through all the sub-folders and crops the .jpg files.

Answer (score 4):

macOS has `sips` image processing tool integrated. Cropping functions available are:

```
    -c, --cropToHeightWidth pixelsH pixelsW 
        --cropOffset offsetY offsetH
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy with sips: just set the offset to start the cropping:

```
sips --cropOffset 1 1 -c <height> <width> -o output.png input.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I have scanned some pages and all ~130 pages needs the lower ~1/8 of the page cut off.

Using `mogrify` didn't work for me,

```
a@a-NC210-NC110:/media/a/LG/AC/Learn/Math/Calculus/Workshop/clockwise/aa$ mogrify -quality 100 -crop 2592×1850+0+0 *.jpg  
mogrify.im6: invalid argument for option `2592×1850+0+0': -crop @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/4232.
```

However `convert` did:

```
a@a-NC210-NC110:~/Pictures/aa$ convert '*.jpg[2596x1825+0+0]' letter%01d.jpg  
a@a-NC210-NC110:~/Pictures/aa$
```

I learnt this [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php) under the *Inline Image Crop* section.

Notice my syntax: I had to put my geometry in brackets: `[]`.

Using the successful syntax above but with mogrify simply didn't work, producing:

```
a@a-NC210-NC110:~/Pictures/aa$ mogrify '*.jpg[2596x1825+0+0]' letter%01d.jpg
mogrify.im6: unable to open image `letter%01d.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638.
```

---

```
Linux a-NC210-NC110 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:12 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
Lubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

Comment: This was because you used the character '×' instead of a 'x'