# OpenCV error: Image step is wrong

Tags: linux, opencv

I'm going through this tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html#creating-the-csv-file

Everything goes well, but running the face recognition script gives this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong (The matrix is not continuous, thus its number of rows can not be changed)
```

I'm using Ubuntu so I'm not exactly sure how to implement the solution found here:  [Getting OpenCV Error "Image step is wrong" in Fisherfaces.train() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961586/getting-opencv-error-image-step-is-wrong-in-fisherfaces-train-method/11036304#11036304)

I rebuilt in debug mode but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the same error with this face recognition example. I got rid of the error by giving same ratio(1:1) images.

Crop the images using this script (see this as well [Command line batch image cropping tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893244/command-line-batch-image-cropping-tool))

```
#!/bin/bash
width=92;
height=92;
x_offset=0;
y_offset=10;
filelist=`ls | grep '.pgm'`
for image_file in $filelist
do
  convert -crop ${width}x${height}+${x_offset}+${y_offset} \
    $image_file $image_file
done
```

this will crop the images in a folder, so u need to put this script in the same directory where your images are.

Also you  should give absolute path inside the csv file.